# 2FA App Store - Application specific passwords and FASTLANE_SESSION can't be used more than once?

Tags: ios, swift, continuous-integration, fastlane, two-factor-authentication

I'm setting up a pipeline with Azure, which works fine for the first time, but when I try to use it again it doesn't use the  application specific password anymore.

**Here's what I have done:**

- Reinstalled fastlane.
- Created a new application specific password at App Store.
- Created a new FASTLANE_SESSION running the command spaceauth -u user@email.com on terminal.

It works once in a while, usually after reinstalling Fastlane.

Apart from this, the pipeline works fine.

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'macos-latest'

steps:
- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: 'iOSDistributionCertificate.p12'
    certPwd: 'xxxxx'
    keychain: 'temp'

- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  inputs:
    provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
    provProfileSecureFile: '4e932719-f9bd-4d3e-b4e6-08b35260c632.mobileprovision'

- task: ios-bundle-version@1
  inputs:
    sourcePath: 'BookingApp/info.plist'
    versionCodeOption: 'buildid'
    versionCode: '$(Build.BuildId)'
    versionCodeOffset: '0'
    printFile: true

- task: Xcode@5
  displayName: 'Build the app using Xcode'
  inputs:
    actions: 'build'
    sdk: 'iphoneos12.4'
    configuration: 'Release'
    scheme: 'BookingApp'
    packageApp: true
    xcodeVersion: 10 # Options: 8, 9, 10, default, specifyPath
    signingOption: 'auto'
    useXcpretty: false # Makes it easier to diagnose build failures
    xcWorkspacePath: '**/*.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace'

- task: AppStoreRelease@1
  inputs:
    serviceEndpoint: 'Booking App Connection'
    appType: 'iOS'
    ipaPath: '**/*.ipa'
    releaseTrack: 'TestFlight'
    installFastlane: false
```

Here's the output :

```
[command]fastlane pilot upload -u *** -i /Users/runner/runners/2.158.0/work/1/s/output/$(SDK)/$(Configuration)/BookingApp.ipa -q XXXXXXXX -r XXXXXX PLC
[15:59:22]: [33mGet started using a Gemfile for fastlane https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/#use-a-gemfile[0m
[15:59:23]: Sending anonymous analytics information
[15:59:23]: Learn more at https://docs.fastlane.tools/#metrics
[15:59:23]: No personal or sensitive data is sent.
[15:59:23]: You can disable this by adding `opt_out_usage` at the top of your Fastfile
[15:59:23]: Login to App Store Connect (***)
Session loaded from environment variable is not valid. Continuing with normal login.
Two-factor Authentication (6 digits code) is enabled for account '***'
More information about Two-factor Authentication: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915
If you're running this in a non-interactive session (e.g. server or CI)
check out https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/spaceship#2-step-verification
(Input `sms` to escape this prompt and select a trusted phone number to send the code as a text message)
(You can also set the environment variable `SPACESHIP_2FA_SMS_DEFAULT_PHONE_NUMBER` to automate this)
(Read more at: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/spaceship/docs/Authentication.md#auto-select-sms-via-spaceship-2fa-sms-default-phone-number)
```

Any idea on what could be the issue ? I'm using fastlane 2.28.3

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should switch to using an API Key for App Store Connect instead of a login + password + session, thus there will no longer have 2 factor auth involved. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64340709/1752620