# Two-factor Authentication With fastlane

Tags: continuous-integration, fastlane, two-factor-authentication

Im releasing my app to firebase distribution throw Fastlane while using CI machine.
Im facing an issue with the 2FA.

Im using Match to retrieve my certificates.
This is what I have under "Appfile"

```
app_identifier "com.example.example" # the bundle 
apple_id "appleAcount@gmail.com" # Your Apple
team_id "abcd..."  # Developer Portal Team ID
ENV["FASTLANE_USER"] = "appleAcount@gmail.com"
ENV["MATCH_PASSWORD"] = ""
ENV["FASTLANE_PASSWORD"] = ""
ENV["FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD"] = ""
```

This is the error I'm receiving:

> Two-factor Authentication (6 digits code) is enabled for account
> 'appleAcount@gmail.com' More information about Two-factor
> Authentication: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915
>
> If you're running this in a non-interactive session (e.g. server or
> CI) check out
> https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/spaceship#2-step-verification
>
> (Input `sms` to escape this prompt and select a trusted phone number
> to send the code as a text message)
>
> (You can also set the environment variable
> `SPACESHIP_2FA_SMS_DEFAULT_PHONE_NUMBER` to automate this) (Read more
> at:
> https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/spaceship/docs/Authentication.md#auto-select-sms-via-spaceship_2fa_sms_default_phone_number)
>
> Please enter the 6 digit code:

I have read this "https://docs.fastlane.tools/best-practices/continuous-integration/" but with no luck. can anyone help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 72):

The fastlane team did a great job ❤ in recent releases (from [2.157.0](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/releases/tag/2.157.0) to [2.163.0](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/releases/tag/2.163.0) so far) to support the use of an [API key for App Store Connect API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/creating_api_keys_for_app_store_connect_api) in many actions (`pilot`, `deliver`, `match`, etc. - the status for each tool is [available here](https://docs.fastlane.tools/app-store-connect-api/#supported-actionstools)).

Using an API key removes the need to provide an Apple account to authenticate and authorize the fastlane actions to do their operations on App Store Connect, which also means that you will no longer be fighting with 2 factor issues on your CI machine or have to manually regenerate a session via `fastlane spaceauth` when it becomes invalid.

From [App Store Connect API Key page](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/access/api):

> Generating an API key allows you to configure, authenticate, and use one or more Apple services for that key. Keys don’t expire, but can’t be modified to access more services once created. You can have a maximum of 50 active keys at a time

There are other benefits of using an API key and it is the recommended solution as explained in the [fastlane documentation](https://docs.fastlane.tools/app-store-connect-api/):

> fastlane has historically used Apple IDs with username and password to
> authenticate using a cookie-based web session. fastlane will continue
> using this same cookie-based web session to authenticate with an
> unofficial version of the App Store Connect API.
>
> However, it is **recommended** to use the API Key authentication when you
> are able to. The benefits include:
>
> - No 2FA needed
> - Better performance
> - Documented API
> - Increased reliability

I will not detail the steps to set up and use an API key here as it is already well explained in [the documentation](https://docs.fastlane.tools/app-store-connect-api/) but here are the main steps:

1. Create a new API key from App Store Connect (you must have the "Account Holder" role to create one) and assign it the **App Manager** role (cf. [Role permissions documentation](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/deve5f9a89d7)),
2. Store the key and its info on your CI,
3. In your `Fastfile`, call the [`app_store_connect_api_key`](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/app_store_connect_api_key/) action with the values stored in 2.
4. Pass the value returned by 3. as an `api_key` parameter when you call an action, or let the action retrieve its value by itself from the lane context (if it supports it).

2FA problem due to invalid session:

[image]

Should vanish :)

[image]

Comment: This method is great, but it has a problem ...  it's doesn't work in most CI like Bitrise and others. In there, one still needs to use session-based authentication which is valid for 30 days. https://devcenter.bitrise.io/getting-started/configuring-bitrise-steps-that-require-apple-developer-account-data/#fastlane-step

Comment: I've never used Bitrise but indeed that's too bad they don't offer this option (my screenshots were on Github Actions), but that's a limitation of the CI not of fastlane. This may change in the future as Bitrise have already deprecated the old session-based authorization for iOS Auto Provision for automatic code signing (but not with fastlane): https://blog.bitrise.io/app-store-connect-api-on-bitrise

Comment: @Vizllx we got it to work for Bitrise. We just added the app store connect api key to the secrets.

Comment: `download_metadata` doesn't accept the `api_key` value, so I am not able to make it work. And idea?

Comment: When you create the API key, ensure you give it the "App Manager" role.

Comment: @manueGE `download_metadata` is a feature of `deliver` which supports the API key based on the fastlane doc. If you are getting an error, you should report it to the fastlane repo: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues.

@diachedelic you're right, I've updated the answer.

Comment: @diachedelic, I think that was the problem with my setup. I used the **Developer** role enough, since it "[m]anages development and delivery of an app," but it didn't work.

Answer (score 10):

You need to set up a environment variable 'FASTLANE_SESSION'='---\n....\n' token.

To get this token you need to authenticate manually using this command:

> fastlane spaceauth -u YOUR_APP_STORE_EMAIL

example fastlane spaceauth -u joe@test.com.

You will need to revalidate every 2-3 weeks (some say 30 days) your session. The process is kinda of a pain right now.

Comment: Our session is expiring every 8 hours... it's not a good solution at all :/ But at least it uses the fact that our account is invited in multiple other accounts. With the API key we have to ask every client to create an API key in order for the automation to work.

Comment: I was getting error "Could not login to App Store Connect" when requesting web session with fastlane spaceauth -u YOUR_APP_STORE_EMAIL. But it fixed with calling it with sudo (sudo fastlane spaceauth -u YOUR_APP_STORE_EMAIL). May be it would be useful anybody.

Comment: As the official Fastlane docs explain (https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/authentication/) this is one method of doing it but as the session runs out quickly, I don't think this is a recommended approach to do on a CI.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a new App Store Connect API Key in the [Users page](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/access/api)

   - For more info, go to the [App Store Connect API Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/creating_api_keys_for_app_store_connect_api)
   - Give your API Key an appropriate role for the task at hand. You can read more about roles in [Permissions in App Store Connect](https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/)
2. Download the newly created API Key file (.p8)
   This file cannot be downloaded again after the page has been refreshed
3. Add key in your project

```html
lane :release do
  api_key = app_store_connect_api_key(
    key_id: "D383SF739",
    issuer_id: "6053b7fe-68a8-4acb-89be-165aa6465141",
    key_filepath: "./AuthKey_D383SF739.p8",
    duration: 1200, # optional (maximum 1200)
    in_house: false # optional but may be required if using match/sigh
  )

  pilot(api_key: api_key)
end
```

[more details](https://docs.fastlane.tools/app-store-connect-api/)

Comment: or just `pilot` at the end.