# 2 Factor Authentication in CI-CD process for app store in azure DevOps

Tags: ios, azure-devops, continuous-integration, fastlane, two-factor-authentication

I am trying to release the app to the app store but as 2FA is now mandatory for the apple account I am facing an issue while uploading the app to the store.

I tried using `FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD` as per the [this link](https://docs.fastlane.tools/best-practices/continuous-integration/#application-specific-passwords)
but it did not work out.

[image]

I have added an app-specific password in the service connection as well.

[image]

after adding an app-specific password in that and got the following error:
also, it is saying that you can pass the password using `FASTLANE_PASSWORD` in the environment variable but I don't know how to pass it.
[image]

I went through the answer provided by

[Two-factor Authentication With Fastlane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63508108/two-factor-authentication-with-fastlane)
 but it's not helping me with Azure DevOps. Is there another way to make it work?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried with azure dev ops?

Comment: @Paulw11 I updated the question...can you please help with this?

Comment: Have you tried removing the value from the password field?  You only want an app specific password.

Comment: you mean in the service connection I should remove the password and just keep an app-specific password...right?

Comment: Yes. That is right

Comment: @Paulw11 I tried that and got the warning `##[warning]Your fastlane session is incorrect and app specific id is not set. Please set correct fastlane session or app specific id` also task is failed...I just updated the question again...can you please check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229815/discussion-between-ragesh-pikalmunde-and-paulw11).

Comment: can you plz share your fastlane invocation?

Answer (score 3):

When you download the API key, you will get a .p8 certificate (e.g `AuthKey_426ZIF325NY.p8`) but most probably you cannot save this file as a pipeline variable, but you can save it as a string.

Open terminal and go to your `Download Folder` then open your file with some Text Editor (preferred) e.g `vim AuthKey_426ZIF325NY.p8` or `nano AuthKey_426ZIF325NY.p8`, but you can use any editor you are familiar with (e.g VS Code).

You will get something like this:[image: .p8 certificate]

You need to to save this key as string, but you cannot just copy the content, because there are some `\n` symbols you do not see and you will not copy them with normal copy/paste. So you need to add them manually and delete the line brakes:

Before:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
GTAGTAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGTTqGSM49AwEHBHkwdwIBAQQg6YnlZ7oLdukc99KL
TZBVNjYeCpNQtZh3uY2SZw6jh+igCgYIKoZIzj0DAQehRANCAAQ2dMU6ss1I3760
OLjYhPBLn5f1T9ZXVbI4kFcKARM/JfPOKh7rK95LHoEOGdpBQHEaAmZo0x2pnF1+
AhD4UTiE
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

After:

```
"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nGTAGTAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGTTqGSM49AwEHBHkwdwIBAQQg6YnlZ7oLdukc99KL\nTZBVNjYeCpNQtZh3uY2SZw6jh+igCgYIKoZIzj0DAQehRANCAAQ2dMU6ss1I3760\nOLjYhPBLn5f1T9ZXVbI4kFcKARM/JfPOKh7rK95LHoEOGdpBQHEaAmZo0x2pnF1+\n
AhD4UTiE\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"
```

Now save this "After" parameter (but use your certificate) as a pipeline variable with name `key`.
You Upload Job (Upload to TestFlight) needs access to this certificate and other two variables.

If you want, you can post your fastlane upload lane here and I will write you the additonal part.

Answer (score 2):

How about setting all of the three variables to be environment variables?

- **`FASTLANE_PASSWORD`**
- **`FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD`**
- **`FASTLANE_SESSION`**

In addition, please note that, unlike the normal pipeline variables, the secret pipeline variables will not be automatically mapped as environment variables on the agents during the pipeline running. You need to explicitly map secret variables to be environment variables. For details, see "[**Set secret variables**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables)".

**[UPDATE]**

The **`FASTLANE_PASSWORD`** should be the password of your iCloud account (or App Store Connect account). However usually it is not necessary in CI/CD pipeline.

You can try the following command line:

```
fastlane spaceauth -u <your-email-address>
```

This command line can generate a login session for your Apple ID in advance. Then you need to store the generated value inside the **`FASTLANE_SESSION`** environment variable on the agent machine.

To view more details, you can see "[**Storing a manually verified session using `spaceauth`**](https://docs.fastlane.tools/best-practices/continuous-integration/#storing-a-manually-verified-session-using-spaceauth)".

Comment: where can I get FASTLANE_PASSWORD`? is that app store password that I need to use?

Comment: Hi @RageshPikalmunde, I have updated my answer with more information. Please check with it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer...I created the `FASTLANE_SESSION` and it's working now, though I doubt that all 3 needs to be set up in the environment variable just `FASTLANE_SESSION` should work. I will check and let you know.

Comment: Hi @RageshPikalmunde, you're welcome. Any update, feel free to tell us.

Comment: Hi @RageshPikalmunde, how are things going? Does `FASTLANE_SESSION` work for you?

Comment: yes it works, but `FASTLANE_SESSION ` is expiring in 1 or 2 days so I had to create a new one, I am trying to implement things with `apple connect API` so that problem will be solved permentaly https://docs.fastlane.tools/app-store-connect-api/

Comment: Hi @RageshPikalmunde, please go ahead.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the `FASTLANE_SESSION` is not valid anymore, so you need to create a new: https://docs.fastlane.tools/best-practices/continuous-integration/

Recommended way is to use the App Store Connect API, so you do not need 2FA and do not need to recreate fastlane session:
https://docs.fastlane.tools/app-store-connect-api/

You need to set `key_id`, `issuer_id` and `key` once (the key can be stored as a String) and no need to change it ever.

The Account Holder must give you access to the App Store Connect API.

Comment: can you please tell me how and where to add that `key_id, issuer_id` and `key`  in azure DevOps?

Comment: @RageshPikalmunde Under the ApplStoreRelease task in your AzureDevOps you need to change your auth method to `App Store Connect API Key`. Once you changed that, you'll see this 3 fields show up

Answer (score 1):

There are few solutions, but you can use pipeline variables for instance.

Name: `key_id`
Value: `<You will find this in AppStoreConnect>`

Name: `issuer_id`
Value: `<You will find this in AppStoreConnect>`

Name: `key`
Value: `<Open the .p8 Certificate in editor and add '\n' for every newline>`

Comment: Name: `key` Value: `<Open the .p8 Certificate in editor and add '\n' for every newline>` I am confused about this, like where exactly this .p8 file needs to be uploaded and how to access it, can you please explain?